# Extract item from css LESS list by name

Tags: css, less

If I have a list in less like:

```
@colors: 'red' #f00, 'green' #0f0, 'blue' #00f;
```

I know that I can loop over the list and get the colors, but what if I want to get a specific one? Say I want to do

```
extract(@colors, 'green')
```

to get #0f0 out of the list. Is there a way to do this? If it takes a few steps instead of 1 that is fine, I am just curious if it is possible. The documentation only mentions getting an item from a list by index.

http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Lists](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists#less-plugin-lists) Less plugin has [`at`](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists/blob/master/docs/ref.md#at) function, so your code may be as simple as:

```css
@colors: red #f00, green #0f0, blue #00f;

div {
    color: at(@colors, green); 
}
```

## - - -

*Original "Legacy Less" answer:*

There's no dedicated function, but it's not a problem to write a mixin for this:

```
@colors:
    'red'   #f00,
    'green' #0f0,
    'blue'  #00f;

usage {
    .by-key(@colors, 'green');
    property: @by-key;
}

// ............................
// impl.

.by-key(@array, @key, @fallback...) {
    .-(length(@array));
    .-(@i) when (@i > 0) {.-((@i - 1))}
    .-(@i) when (@key = extract(extract(@array, @i), 1)) {
        @by-key: extract(extract(@array, @i), 2);
    }

    .--() {@by-key: @fallback} .--;
}
```

What's happening inside `.by-key` mixin?

- `.-` is a mixin to [loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) trough `@array` to find the pair of interest.
- `.-(length(@array));` launches the first iteration (starting from the last `@array` index)
- `.-(@i) when (@i > 0) ...` is the iteration mixin definition that simply invokes next iteration (until the first `@array` index) - thus these two form our recursive loop.
- `.-(@i) when (@key = ...` is another iteration definition that compares current item key with the key of interest and if they match it defines the `@by-key` variable we'll use as [the return](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature) value.
- And finally `.--() {@by-key: @fallback} .--;` is the definition and immediate call of another mixin which also defines `@by-key` variable that will come into effect if no value with the specified key is found in the loop before. (hence if you call the mixin in above snippet as `.by-key(@colors, 'banana', #123);` it will return `#123`. This "fallback" part may be omitted and then the code will result in a error if no key is found in the array (something like "variable `@by-key` is not defined").

Comment: Could you explain what some of that does? I'm not really sure what .- and .--() etc does. If you have time could you just add a quick comment about what each piece is doing? I have been trying to learn less better, but as far as I can tell these advanced type techniques aren't in the documentation

Comment: @Kevin `.-` and `.--` are just mixin names. What you can see there is just plain [Less loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) to find the pair of interest plus a bit more stuff to [return](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature) the found value. I'll add a few more comments to the code later.

Comment: Thank you. I have been learning less quite a bit, but I am not used to using - as mixin names. I've seen it in a few mixin libraries and wasn't sure what it did, I didn't know you could name mixins with characters like that. Also I have to use visual studio since that is the project we are working on, and this shows all kinds of undeclared mixin "warnings" and whatnot even though it compiles. So VS makes it hard for me to feel confident about some of the things I try when its just showing me errors that are not errors clearly. Changed this to the accepted answer!

Comment: Just in case, in Less identifiers can even begin with a digit, e.g. `@1` and and `.1` are valid variable and mixin names... Speaking of `.-`, yes, it might be confusing at first, but as soon as you get to use to it becomes quite handy to name internal auxiliary mixins and variables (instead of `.do-the-stuff`, `@tmp` and `.loop` (the latter is also quite popular to name mixins like these, but it's still incorrect since there neither the mixin definition nor the point it's invoked are really "the loop", not counting it's also quite cumbersome to repeat it for 4 times in code like above)).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation. Now it makes more sense. VS still gives errors, and when I use the for code it tells me .-each is an undeclared mixin. It is probably just a problem with VS and will still compile though, I haven't checked yet.

Comment: Yes, VS uses its own parser to check the Less code and this parser is known to be not aware of vast amount of modern Less features (hence all those false "errors").

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe you can extract by a text value, only an index.

You need to run `extract` twice, first to split the inherant key value pairs in your starting array to just get an array of the values, then extract the required value:

```
property: extract(extract(@array, @item),2);
```

Where `@array` is your array, and `@item` is the numeric index you wish to retrive. I dont beleive you can referance text keys.

So, in your example, you would need to do:

```
property: extract(extract(@colors, 2),2);
```

Comment: That's what I thought. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a way out there I was overlooking. Thanks! This way is fine, I just wanted to make it more readable if I store things in an array, so I could pass in a text value instead of a number and when looking at the less you would know what it is referencing