# Building of a string, which depends on variable number of parameters

Tags: css, less

My question is: how to build a string in Less, which depends on variable number of parameters. For instance, I would like to make a mixin, which helps me to write `@font-face` CSS rules. So I need to build `src:...` fonts property for arbitrary number of formats (.eot, .ttf, .oft, .woff, .woff2, .svg) of my font. Here is my Less loop to process all font formats in list:

```
// @some-types - it is my font formats list, just smth. like 'otf', 'eot',...
// @old-src-value - it is string with src for my font from previous loop
// @counter - it is my loop counter 

.make-font-src(@some-types; @old-src-value; @counter) when (@counter <= length(@some-types)) {

    // Here we get next font format from @some-types
    @font-type: extract(@some-types, @counter);

    // Used for building 'format("opentype")' - like part of src value string
    .get-font-format(@font-type);

    // Building a part of src value string for this iteration
    @src-value: e('@{old-src-value}, url("@{font-path}@{font-filename}.@{font-type}") format("@{font-format}")');

    // Recursive call of this mixin for looping
    .make-font-src(@some-types; @src-value; (@counter + 1));
}
```

So I'm stuck in how to fetch complete src value string, when all font formats will be processed in the loop? Also please refer to [this codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wvyvja).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong comment earlier, this would not cause a recursive definition error because you have used a different variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this would not cause a recursive definition error because you have assigned the value to a different variable and then used it. However, it seems like Less is processing the property-value setting line as soon as the first iteration of the loop is completed. You can verify this by changing the `counter` value for the first iteration itself to 2 or more.

One solution (a better approach to the problem in my opinion) would be to use the [property merging with comma](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature-comma) feature and set the property-value pair directly like in the below snippet:

```
.make-font-src(@some-types; @counter) when (@counter <= length(@some-types)) {
  @font-path: 'some/test/path/';
  @font-filename: 'Arial';
  @font-type: extract(@some-types, @counter);
  src+: e('url("@{font-path}@{font-filename}.@{font-type}") format("@{font-type}")');
  .make-font-src(@some-types; (@counter + 1));
}
div.test {
  .make-font-src('eot', 'woff', 'svg'; 1);
}
```

This when compiled would produce the following output:

```
div.test {
  src: url("some/test/path/Arial.eot") format("eot"), 
       url("some/test/path/Arial.woff") format("woff"),
       url("some/test/path/Arial.svg") format("svg");
}
```

Comment: This solution looks more elegant, nice!

Comment: And just in case you don't need `& {}` there (local mixin variables always have the highest precedence in the mixin itself so neither prev. nor next iterations can interfere).

Comment: Oops, was trying something else with it and seem to have forgot to remove. Thanks for pointing out @seven-phases-max :) The extra `font-format` variable was not required too.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found my own solution: if we add special 'getter' mixin with guard, which triggered on last iteration of the loop, we can get full src value from our loop mixin.

```
.getter(@cond; @list) when (@cond = length(@list)) {
    @font-src-full: @src-value;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle with demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjRVxZ?editors=010)

Comment: Well, yes, if you use a variable for such concatenation the loop should have a "terminal" iteration specialization to define the result variable (classic examples are [1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/less/mixins/grid-framework.less#L6), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23954580/2712740), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27389130/2712740) etc.).

Comment: Though for the particular use-case, I wonder if a loop actually would fit a real font definition since `src` statement of font-face with all backward-compatibility and browser workarounds [won't follow a strict pattern](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/4dd906599e3bd57e8605) (i.e. I'd rather hardcoded every `src` manually with a condition (or a list of conditions) for each if necessary).